# How many fingers do the aliens have?

Tags: mathematics, cipher, symbols

A message has come from another galaxy. The radio receiver detects 7 different wave forms and translates those into letters; now your task is pretty easy.

Decipher the message, and determine how many fingers the aliens have on one hand.

> CCCVVFFBBGGHHTTCVCFCBCHCVVCCC

Do you think the alien's idea was good? Any answers need to be accompanied with an explanation.

**Hint:**

Perfectly equivalent message if aliens have 2 finger less

> CCCVVFFBBGGCVCFCBCVVCVBCCC

Comment: Yes it was better just asking for how many fingers in one hand. I already edited thanks, feel free to improve that further. The point is that number of hands and feet does not matter at all.

Comment: Gotcha. Good stuff.

Comment: How do you know the message is related to fingers?

Comment: Because I know the alien who wrote it.

Comment: How many fingers does your alien friend have on one hand?

Answer (score 7):

I initially thought the aliens have

> 7 fingers per hand-like-thing

Because the code sent has

> 7 values

and beyond that

> translating C->0, V->1, F->2... the second half of the message, using the 0 value as a separator, is 1,2,3,5,11(8 base 7) The Fibonacci sequence.

---

However, Given the hint

> It's possible the C is a null value, and the 0 digit was attached to the other end of the stream.

That gives us a sequence of

> 1,2,3,5,7 which is almost Primes, but starts with 1.
>  or 1,2,3,5,11 base 6, 1,2,3,11,13 base 4.

Which would mean that the Aliens have

> Either 3, or 6 fingers per hand.

Comment: Almost correct, with one problem. You had one oversight about the meaning of values, which yielded to a uncorrect sequence.. I can add a hint later :) you could as well just interpreted the sequence as 01020305011000 according to your interpretation

Comment: @DarioOO I was kinda assuming it was a SETI like message, "These are our digits. Look they're digits, check out this simple math. The 0 then represents not only 0, but the Base State/Carrier Wave, I treated it as a seperator because the sequence didn't call for it.

Comment: Yes your idea is right, I'm not sure how SETI exactly work, but I hope they don't use a symbol both as separator and as a digit ;) otherwise aliens could have been already laughing at us XD

Comment: A number of messages sent to space (e.g. [Arecibo Message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message) and [Cosmic Call](http://blog.plover.com/aliens/dd/intro.html)) used binary to transmit black & white images, and interesting things like digits only appear once the image is assembled. I would recommend reading through the second link when you get a chance, interesting stuff. (Also sort of a bonus puzzle!)

Comment: If this solution is correct, does that mean humans have 10 fingers on each hand?  (Or am I missing something?  [And, no, I don't mean "am I missing 5 fingers on each hand"!])

Comment: this solution is not totally correct but has almost the correct idea. Because we have 10 fingers we have developed numbers in a way..

Comment: @Phlarx Cosmic Call is really interesting however since they wanted to avoid dataloss, they should have added magnified versions of numeric gliphs so that aliens have easier life reconstructing corrupted gliphs.

Comment: I'm thinking 8 fingers, or 4 on each hand, but I have questions about how we know we didn't miss any wavelengths, etc., but I'm interested in seeing how this is solved.

Comment: @Sconibulus. Base 6 with 0 added at end is correct. The boostrap sequence is just to agree on which symbols to use inside the message, a symbol is just much more resilient to signal loss/noise. C is indeed a separator. Each symbol can be whatever, a waveform or a sequence of bits. Withouth the boostrap the message could be interpreted in many different ways.

Answer (score 5):

After reading the [Sconibulus very interesting answer, (he is the real solver)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42202/30011) the two sequence are

> 000 / 112233445566 / 01020305011 /000 (X fingers per hand)

and

> 000 / 11223344 / 010203011013  /000 (X-2 fingers per hand)

And this is my possible and alternative interpretation

> Aliens are not transmitting the Fibonacci sequence, nor the PI, nor the EUler/Neper number etc. First and last part of the sequence are like CQ morse code: my call starts with CQ CQ CQ wich means "Hey I'm calling here, there is some one who is listening? Be ready for my transmission!" or "End of the message, I will not transmit anymore, now take a cofee ".

Second part

> 112233445566 seems to be like "Check out how many different digits we have! 6 different state!" (4 in the alternative situation). As Sconibulus pointed out, 0 is the Carrier Wave. So the signals started with to impulses (1 sec of transmission, 1 sec off, 1 sec on, 1 sec off, 1 sec on and then the values as peaks in the wave)

Third part

> 01020305011 becomes  1 2 3 5 11 wich in base 6 is  1 2 3 5 7 /
>   010203011013 becomes 1 2 3 11 13 wich in base 4 is 1 2 3 5 7.
>  They are the first prime numbers (except for 1) in sequence.

Conclusion: How many finger?

> Assuming that humans use base 10 because have 10 fingers, assuming that clever and advanced aliens could not exist without fingers, the should have 6 (or 4) fingers. On both hands? Could be, since both are even numbers. But what about number 1 (wich is not a "real" prime number). Assuming that aliens have the same rigid behaviour of our math teachers in terms of definitions, we could read the sequence as "Look at my beautiful numerical system based on 1 hand: I am telling you that the first prime numbers are 2 3 5 7..." And, after all, who can assure us that aliens have exactly 2 hands?

One more note

> My solution is wrong if you note that nor in the first neither in the second aliens use their last digit. But it could be transmitted (as a composite value) in terms of amplitude of the wave to say "I am transmitting between ZERO (C) and MAX state T (or G)" instead of  "I have 1,2,3,4,5,6 fingers. 6 different states in my numerical system but I will never use the last because if I would have 10 fingers my bigger state were nine!"

Sorry for some bad english! Thank you for the question

Comment: Yes, Aliens should have showed a sequence long enough to use the "0" digit (since the base is even the digit can only appear in intermediate positions). Or better even started with a sequence that shows numbers just increasing. Puzzling.SE is increadibly useful for testing SETI like messages. :). The 1 was included in the sequence of primes because without it it could be ambiguos if the first digit was 1 or 0 instead.

Comment: You got a important point which is identifying that the first part of the message is a "HandShake". "Ehi I'm going to use these symbols. As long as I'm able to award the Bounty I will award both answers +50 (+50 to one, and then start another Bounty)

Comment: The system do not allow to award 50, so you will get 100 _-_ enojy XD

Comment: @DarioOO thank you for this reward and for let me imagine to work in the SETI program with real aliens! XD

Comment: No problem :) planning to add more SETI like questions in future :)

Answer (score 0):

(I found answer in JavaScript)

My answer is:

> 6, 3 fingers for hand.

Why?

1

> var msg = "CCCVVFFBBGGHHTTCVCFCBCHCVVCCC".length;
> Output: 29

2

> I delete the duplicate letters: "CVFBGHT".

3

> I create a variable.
> var a = "CVFBGHT".length;

4

> I subtract the length of whole message with the message without duplicate letters. 
>  var b = msg / a;
> Output: 4.142857142857143

5

> b becomes a string, and I count the length of string.
> b.toString().length;
> Output: 17

6

> "hands" word has 5 letters, 
> var word = 17 - 5;
> Output: 12

7

> word/2 = 6.

8

> The aliens have 3 fingers in each hand.

Comment: Why -1? Let me know why

Comment: umm... 29/7 isn't evenly divisible, any finite string you get out of that is an artifact of your interpreter. You also don't explain WHY you're doing any of the things you're doing.

Comment: On the other hand, welcome to Puzzling! Thank you for showing your work, and for your use of spoiler tags.

Comment: Arbitrary Manning of numbers can yield any result you want. Simplest explaination is Always prefferred. DIdn't downvoted

Comment: @Sconibulus 29/7 is disivible, It returns 4.142857142857143. I convert 4.142857142857143 in string.

Comment: @DarioOO I hope you liked my solutino

Comment: @1415 just saying, 29 is not divisible by 7.... specifically in mathematics,    "(of a number) capable of being divided by another number without a remainder" is a number which is divisible by another...